# Regexextract issue on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Got a DB in google spreadsheet. There are lots of unique cells containing more than one e-mail. 
I´m trying to extract them using `=Regexextract(E2;"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}")`, but it extract just the first e-mail on the list.

Here's a screenshot of the sheet:

[image]

Any clue on how to do it to extract all of them?

Comment: see my answer below - this effectively extracts all of them

Comment: This question was cross-posted to other sites: [1]. http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3496/65, [2]. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs-es/vgnWpwFT5g4. As was mentioned in 1 crossposting isn't bad by itself but this should be mentioned as courtesy to others, specially when the content of question is a duplicate/translation of the other posts.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because in [2] there there is a followup post where the OP says that the email addresses are included inside a text block and the image included in this post doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1):

If you data consistently looks like the example you showed - the easiest would be:

```
=SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))
```

this effectively splits out all the emails using the newline as the delimiter.

If you still want to use regex, you can dynamically create capture groups based on the number of emails in a cell by trying this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("\n?(\w+@\w+\.\w+)",COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"@"))-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `regexextract` cannot extract repeated matches.

Here is a workaround:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(split(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s+",";"),";"),"(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")))
```

where

- `REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s+",";")` replaces all spaces (including line breaks) with ;
- `split(REGEXREPLACE(...),";")` converts it to an array
- `REGEXEXTRACT(split(...),(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")` extracts the e-mail address
- `iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(...))` returns nothing if there's no match
- and `arrayformula(iferror(...))` ensures `iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(...))` can handle the array created by `split()`

You didn't specify how the result should be displayed. If you want a comma delimited list, do `join(",", result)`

Answer (score -1):

Try `REGEXREPLACE` "Replace part of a text string with a different text string using regular expressions"

```
=REGEXREPLACE(E2;"([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})";"$1")
```

**Where:**

`():` Capturing group

`$1:` Replace with content captured in the subpattern

Comment: that just returns the same string, it doesn't split out the email addresses at all